# iterator_to_array is too slow

Tags: php, mongodb

In following PHP script `iterator_to_array` is extremely inefficient (I used a profiler). Is there any better alternative for following code?

```
$new = [];
$rows=(new Mongo())->table1->find(['foo' => 'bar'),
$new['string'] = iterator_to_array($rows);  //Time-consuming part
(new Mongo())->table2->save($new);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no alternative, if you have an iterator and you want an array, you need to iterate the iterator and pass the values to the array, you can do it by yourself using `foreach` or you can use `iterator_to_array`, but if you have many elements in the iterator, the process is time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

How many rows are actually being returned by your first query? Presumably, the total data is less than 16MB, since you're storing it into one field in a new document.

Did your profiling indicate whether the delay was in network IO or constructing the array? The cursor iteration is actually going to entail a bit of both. If you're seeing a high number of `getmore` operations on the server-side, you could tweak that with [MongoCursor::batchSize()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.batchsize.php) to reduce network roundtrips. This will control the number of documents requested at once by the driver during iteration. By default, the driver will use a batch size of 101, so if your result consisted of a large number of tiny documents, you would expect many roundtrips with tiny payloads. The actual number of documents returned per `getmore` will be limited to 4MB or the batch size, whichever is smaller.

In addition to increasing the batch size, you may want to add a projection to the `find()` if only some fields are of interest to you.

Alternatively, if this is a seldom-used query and you'd like to avoid the network IO, you may want to consider doing the entire operation server-side with the [eval command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) (and the `nolock` option). Just be aware of the caveats (documented near the bottom of the page) before opting to go that route.